# Which SQL Server 2008 data type should be used for image and text data?

Tags: sql-server, database, types

I have a table in SQLServer, and one of the fields is expecting rather mixed data; sometimes it will receive a text value, let's say for the sake of argument:

```
 ASCII ART PICTURE OF A CAT WITH A POORLY SPELT CAPTION
```

Then sometimes it will contain an actual JPEG which contains images of cats with poorly spelt captions. What's the best datatype to use in this instance? A big, long, object.

We can assume that the ASCII art pictures are fairly small, say 16 chars x 16 chars. You could store them in a VARCHAR(256) field, at least if it wasn't for those pesky big 2MB JPEGs that people send.

### Additional bit

Semantically, we can say that both of these are images of cats, albeit in very different formats. The question I guess I'm asking is that if there is an appropriate datatype to handle values which are semantically the same thing, but could come in very different forms.

### Additional bit #2

In this case, the amount of data about our cat varies wildly. Sometimes the cat caption image is very small, and we only need ~256bytes of information to be stored. But sometimes it is very large, if it were a plaintext ASCII cat image, it might take up ~256megabytes, but we can shove it in a JPEG and it only takes up 2megabytes. Yay, moar cat images can be stored on our harddrive! But naturally, I do not want to convert those ~256byte ASCII images to a 2megabyte JPEG, because then I can't fit as many pictures of cats on my harddrive.

In case there's a suggestion along these lines -  I can't make a new format for those 2MB JPEGs, the output will always be 2MB for it to be compatible with the legacy, third-party, closed source cat-caption generator. That generates captions of such incredible awesomeness that rewriting it is a difficult task, and outside of the scope of the software being written.

NB: The actual real life use case is to do with data coming off a genetic analysis machine, if you're interested, but I'd rather the question be a more general use case of cat pictures. This being the internet and all.

### Additional bit #3

We can say that the database structure looks a bit like

```
MyCatContent
    idCatContent INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    catContentType INT NOT NULL REFERENCES CatContentType (catContentType),
    content {whatSortOfFieldIsThis?}

CatContentType
    catContentType INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    description VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
```

Comment: Use VARBINARY(MAX), this should cover all bases.

Comment: VARBINARY for a binary image? to be honest though it sounds like something you probably shouldn't be storing in the database, or at least not in the same field as a short text item.

Comment: Storing text and files in the column is a very poor design choice. Would you store an address and a pdf in the same column? They are different things and need to handled accordingly.

Comment: Why the downvote? Just because something is a bad choice doesn't make the question a bad one .. it makes the answer saying "this is a bad choice" correct.

Comment: On top, bad choice is relative. Given that you can redirect that back to the file system (yes, yes) and it has advantages - forum, blog software (stackexchange) likely store their texts in the database.

Comment: I think calling it a "bad choice" is a hasty generalization. There are several advantages to storing images or files as binary data in the database. Security dictated by the DB instead of DB and file system, simplicity of backup, replication, all changes are logged, etc. It's certainly a choice that has some significant caveats, but universally decrying it as "bad" is going too far. Microsoft has a [very good paper](http://research.microsoft.com/apps/pubs/default.aspx?id=64525) on the topic.

Comment: @BaconBits and TomTom - cheers, yeah - I believe it to be the *right* choice in my particular situation, although I would generally say that having vastly different types of data in one column seems a bit odd. The paper BaconBits linked to is indeed a very good one.

Comment: I take it you have a discriminator column e.g. "originalFileName" or "content-type" or an equivalent?

Comment: @Ben - yeah, added an "additional bit 3" to make that clear - there is a separate table which, in the above case, which allows you to say what the content is.